# Как пройтись по элементам XML?

Tags: xml, jquery

У меня есть XML-ка:

```
<note>
  <elements>
    <button />
    <input />
    <mycontrol></mycontrol>
  </elements>
</note>
```

Как пройтись по всем elements?

Comment: //* уже не работает?

Answer (score 1):

У jQuery есть готовая функция http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```
  var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
```

Comment: наверное, немного не то... нужно, что типа getNextElement()... вызываем её три раза... первый раз получаем button, второй раз input, третий раз - mycontrol

Answer (score 1):

[@sitev_ru](/users/18326/sitev_ru), пройдитесь в цикле

```
var xml = "<note><elements><button /><input /><mycontrol></mycontrol></elements></note>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$('elements *', xmlDoc).each(function(i, el){
    console.log(el);
    // или если нужен объект jQuery
    console.log($(el));
});
```

Comment: Как понять, что button - это и есть button, а input - это и есть input???

Comment: @sitev_ru, свойство **tagName**

    console.log(el.tagName); // button или  input, или mycontrol и т.д.